# How to enable external iis requests in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I used to use external iss access in VS 2013. However since upgrading to 2015 my bindings in the `documents/iss express/config/applicationhost.config` don't seem to apply when debugging in visual studio 2015.

What do I have to do differently in VS2015 in order to test my web api from a mobile device or PC on my local machine?

I am using windows 10 and visual studio 2015 professional.

Comment: Check solution folder's .vs folder.

Comment: There is no such thing in my solutions folder?

Comment: Ps: It was a hidden folder. Hence why I didn't see it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exposing IISExpress Site On Local Network Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709864/exposing-iisexpress-site-on-local-network-visual-studio-2015)