# Exposing IISExpress Site On Local Network Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I have a solution that I was originally building in Visual Studio 2012.  I needed this to be available on my local network so I added an additional IP address binding to this file:

```
C:\Users\<name>\Documents\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config
```

This all works without any issues.  However, when I run the same solution through Visual Studio 2015 the site is no longer available on the network as configured in this file.

How do I configure Visual Studio 2015 to offer the same network availability?

Comment: Have you used Task Manager or ProcExp to check the command line VS2015 uses to launch IISExpress? I guess I'm wondering why it's ignoring your settings in the first place.

Comment: I didn't see this comment, sorry.  I've added my own answer as I figured it out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, no sooner as I had posted this question I figured out the problem.

Visual Studio 2015 doesn't use the global configuration file detailed above by default.  It creates a solution specific version under the solution directory structure here:

```
<solution_dir>\.vs\config\applicationhost.config
```

Or you can add:

```
<UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>True</UseGlobalApplicationHostFile>
```

To your solution .csproj file.